# Python unicode file reencoding

Tags: python, json, unicode

There are so many questions about Unicode decoding in SO and none of this set fits my needs.

Say, I need to process some json data which part is looks like this:

```
  u'message': {
    u'body': u'\u0441\u043f\u0430\u0441\u0438\u0431\u043e \u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u043e\u0435',
    u'user_id': 374298,
    u'title': u' ... ',
    u'date': 1461496370,
    u'read_state': 0,
    u'id': 4325364,
    u'out': 1
  }
```

The only goal is to get rid of unicode to get human readable text in "body" row:

```
  'message': {
    'body': 'cпасибо большое',
    'user_id': 374298,
    'title': ' ... ',
    'date': 1461496370,
    'read_state': 0,
    'id': 4325364,
    'out': 1
  }
```

As soon as there are plenty of json data, I've modified some found python source code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

filePath = "/home/user/foo.txt"

outPath = filePath + ".new"

outText = ""

inF = open(filePath, "rb")
fContent = unicode(inF.read(), 'utf-8')
inF.close()

for everysymbol in fContent:
    if isinstance(everysymbol, unicode):
        outText += everysymbol.decode('cp1251')
    else: 
        pass

fContent = outText


outF = open(outPath, "wb")
outF.write(outText.decode("utf-8"))
outF.close()
```

Unfortunately, this code does not change anything in target file. How do I really decode my data to be human readable?

Comment: change rb and wb to r and w

Answer (score 4):

You data is not json, but already parsed json data.  Python 2 prints dictionaries and lists using `repr()`, which shows non-ASCII characters as escape codes.  Print the string directly to see its content, which uses `str()`:

```
import json

# Your already parsed data
data = {u'message': {
     u'body': u'\u0441\u043f\u0430\u0441\u0438\u0431\u043e \u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u043e\u0435',
     u'user_id': 374298,
     u'title': u' ... ',
     u'date': 1461496370,
     u'read_state': 0,
     u'id': 4325364,
     u'out': 1}}

# Write it to a file to generate real json-encoded data:
with open('foo.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(data,f,indent=2)

# Display actual json-encoded file:
with open('foo.json') as f:
    print f.read()
print

# reparse the data
with open('foo.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Printing dictionaries and lists escapes non-ASCII
print data
print

# But print the string directly and it is fine (assuming your terminal and font supports the characters):

print data[u'message'][u'body']
```

Output:

```
{
  "message": {
    "body": "\u0441\u043f\u0430\u0441\u0438\u0431\u043e \u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u043e\u0435", 
    "user_id": 374298, 
    "title": " ... ", 
    "date": 1461496370, 
    "read_state": 0, 
    "id": 4325364, 
    "out": 1
  }
}

{u'message': {u'body': u'\u0441\u043f\u0430\u0441\u0438\u0431\u043e \u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u043e\u0435', u'user_id': 374298, u'title': u' ... ', u'date': 1461496370, u'read_state': 0, u'id': 4325364, u'out': 1}}

спасибо большое
```

Note that Python 3 no longer escapes printable non-ASCII for `repr()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

filePath = "/home/user/foo.txt"

outPath = filePath + ".new"

with open(filePath, "rb") as f:
    fContent = json.loads(f.read())

with open(outPath, "wb") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(fContent, ensure_ascii=False).encode())
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.